Next.js Write to Google Sheet from Child Component
I'm facing some issues where I wanted to save user entered data from a HTML form to Google Sheet. Here's my file structure:

I'm currently facing these errors:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

The handleSubmit is used in a component that's called in page.js. However, I'm not sure where to correctly place the /api/submit so it can be called. Here's my handleSubmit function for the form:
// app/components/RSVP/index.js

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const form = {
        name,
        email,
        isComing,
        foodOption,
        favSong,
        note,
    }

    const response = await fetch("/api/submit", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(form),
    })

    const content = await response.json()

    console.log(content.body)
    alert(content.data.range)
}

Here's the submit.js
// app/api/submit.js
import { google } from "googleapis"

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method !== "POST") {
        return res.status(405).send({
            message: "Only POST requests are allowed",
        })
    }

    const body = req.body

    try {
        // prepare auth
        const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
            credentials: {
                client_email: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
                private_key: process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY?.replace(
                    /\\n/g,
                    "\n"
                ),
            },
            scopes: [
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
            ],
        })

        const sheets = google.sheets({
            auth,
            version: "v4",
        })

        const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
            spreadsheetId: process.env.GOOGLE_SHEET_ID,
            range: "Sheet1!A1:F1",
            valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
            requestBody: {
                values: [
                    body.name,
                    body.email,
                    body.isComing,
                    body.foodOption,
                    body.favSong,
                    body.note,
                ],
            },
        })
        
        return res.status(200).json({
            data: response.date,
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: "Something went wrong",
        })
    }
}

This is my next.js project version
"dependencies": {
  "next": "14.1.1",
  "react": "^18",
  "react-dom": "^18"
},

If anyone could give me some guidance on the direction of my research, that would be very appreciated.
